# Problem with mass email sent with pdf attachment

Tags: apex, trigger, apex-email-service

I am sending Contact Attachment to Same Contact mail Id for this I have written an apex helper class for sending email template with attachment and Its working but when I doing the same using data loader its attaching all attachment from different record and sending on every mail id.

```
public with sharing class OpportunityMatchingHelper {

public static List<alu_Opportunity_Matching__c> sendEmail(List<alu_Opportunity_Matching__c> oppList) { 

    Map<Id,alu_Opportunity_Matching__c> OppMapByIDs = new Map<Id,alu_Opportunity_Matching__c>();
    List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage> emails = new List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage>();
    List<Messaging.Emailfileattachment> fileAttachments = new List<Messaging.Emailfileattachment>();

    EmailTemplate et=[Select Id,Subject,HtmlValue,Body FROM EmailTemplate WHERE Name=:'Pitched'];       
    for(alu_Opportunity_Matching__c opMap : oppList){
        if(opMap.Application_Status__c == 'Pitched'){
            OppMapByIDs.put(opMap.Applicant_Student_Record__c, opMap);  
        }       
    }
    for (Attachment a : [select Name, Body, BodyLength from Attachment where ParentId = :OppMapByIDs.keySet()])
    {
       Messaging.EmailFileAttachment efa = new Messaging.EmailFileAttachment();
       efa.setFileName(a.Name);
       efa.setBody(a.Body);
       fileAttachments.add(efa);
    }
    system.debug('fileAttachments'+fileAttachments);
    //Contact con = [SELECT Id, Email FROM Contact WHERE Id IN : OppMapByIDs.keySet()];
    for(alu_Opportunity_Matching__c opp :OppMapByIDs.values()){           
        if(opp.Applicant_Student_Record__c != null){
            Messaging.SingleEmailMessage singleMail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
            singleMail.setTargetObjectId(opp.Applicant_Student_Record__c);
            singleMail.setTemplateId(et.Id);
            singleMail.setWhatId(opp.Id);
            singleMail.setSaveAsActivity(false);
            singleMail.setReplyTo('sumit@teqsolution.com');
            singleMail.setSenderDisplayName('Career Development');
            singleMail.setFileAttachments(fileAttachments);
            emails.add(singleMail); 
            system.debug('emails'+emails);
        }
    }  
    system.debug('emails'+emails);
    Messaging.sendEmail(emails);
    return null;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code, you are fetching all the attachments and then adding it to a list **fileAttachments** and then adding it as attachment for the **alu_Opportunity_Matching__c** record. Create a map to store the attachments with each **alu_Opportunity_Matching__c** and then fetch the attachments of each **alu_Opportunity_Matching__c** record using the Map.

```
public with sharing class OpportunityMatchingHelper {

    public static List<alu_Opportunity_Matching__c> sendEmail(List<alu_Opportunity_Matching__c> oppList) { 

    Map<Id,alu_Opportunity_Matching__c> OppMapByIDs = new Map<Id,alu_Opportunity_Matching__c>();
    List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage> emails = new List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage>();

    //List<Messaging.Emailfileattachment> fileAttachments = new List<Messaging.Emailfileattachment>();
    Map<Id, List<Messaging.Emailfileattachment>> fileAttachmentWithOpp = new Map<Id, List<Messaging.Emailfileattachment>>(); 

    EmailTemplate et=[Select Id,Subject,HtmlValue,Body FROM EmailTemplate WHERE Name=:'Pitched'];       
    for(alu_Opportunity_Matching__c opMap : oppList){
        if(opMap.Application_Status__c == 'Pitched'){
            OppMapByIDs.put(opMap.Applicant_Student_Record__c, opMap);  
        }       
    }
    for (Attachment a : [select Name, Body, BodyLength, ParentId from Attachment where ParentId = :OppMapByIDs.keySet()]){
       Messaging.EmailFileAttachment efa = new Messaging.EmailFileAttachment();
       efa.setFileName(a.Name);
       efa.setBody(a.Body);
       if(fileAttachmentWithOpp.containsKey(a.ParentId)){
           List<Messaging.Emailfileattachment> listOfAttachments = fileAttachmentWithOpp.get(a.ParentId);
           listOfAttachments.add(efa);
           fileAttachmentWithOpp.put(a.ParentId, listOfAttachments);
       } else {
           fileAttachmentWithOpp.put(a.ParentId, new List<Messaging.Emailfileattachment>{efa});
       }   
    }
    //system.debug('fileAttachments'+fileAttachments);
    //Contact con = [SELECT Id, Email FROM Contact WHERE Id IN : OppMapByIDs.keySet()];
    for(alu_Opportunity_Matching__c opp :OppMapByIDs.values()){           
        if(opp.Applicant_Student_Record__c != null){
            Messaging.SingleEmailMessage singleMail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
            singleMail.setTargetObjectId(opp.Applicant_Student_Record__c);
            singleMail.setTemplateId(et.Id);
            singleMail.setWhatId(opp.Id);
            singleMail.setSaveAsActivity(false);
            singleMail.setReplyTo('sumit@teqforcesolution.com');
            singleMail.setSenderDisplayName('ALU Career Development');
            if(fileAttachmentWithOpp.containskey(opp.Id)){
                singleMail.setFileAttachments(fileAttachmentWithOpp.ge‌​t(opp.Applicant_Stud‌​ent_Record__c));

            }
            emails.add(singleMail);
            system.debug('emails'+emails);
       }
   }  
   system.debug('emails'+emails);
   Messaging.sendEmail(emails);
   return null;
   }
}
```

Let me know if it works for you.

Answer (score 1):

Hey You are attaching all the files with every email that is why it is going with every email. below is the modified code for this
**Please add attachment inner query in oppList**

```
public with sharing class OpportunityMatchingHelper {

public static List<alu_Opportunity_Matching__c> sendEmail(List<alu_Opportunity_Matching__c> oppList) { 

    Map<Id,alu_Opportunity_Matching__c> OppMapByIDs = new Map<Id,alu_Opportunity_Matching__c>();
    List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage> emails = new List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage>();

    EmailTemplate et=[Select Id,Subject,HtmlValue,Body FROM EmailTemplate WHERE Name=:'Pitched'];       
    for(alu_Opportunity_Matching__c opMap : oppList){
        if(opMap.Application_Status__c == 'Pitched'){
            OppMapByIDs.put(opMap.Applicant_Student_Record__c, opMap);  
        }       
    }

    //Contact con = [SELECT Id, Email FROM Contact WHERE Id IN : OppMapByIDs.keySet()];
    for(alu_Opportunity_Matching__c opp :OppMapByIDs.values()){           
        if(opp.Applicant_Student_Record__c != null){
            List<Messaging.Emailfileattachment> fileAttachments = new List<Messaging.Emailfileattachment>();
            for(attachment attach : opp.attachments){
                Messaging.EmailFileAttachment efa = new Messaging.EmailFileAttachment();
                efa.setFileName(attach.Name);
                efa.setBody(attach.Body);
                fileAttachments.add(efa);
            }
            Messaging.SingleEmailMessage singleMail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
            singleMail.setTargetObjectId(opp.Applicant_Student_Record__c);
            singleMail.setTemplateId(et.Id);
            singleMail.setWhatId(opp.Id);
            singleMail.setSaveAsActivity(false);
            singleMail.setReplyTo('sumit@teqforcesolution.com');
            singleMail.setSenderDisplayName('ALU Career Development');
            if(fileAttachments != null && fileAttachments.size() > 0){
                singleMail.setFileAttachments(fileAttachments);
            }
            emails.add(singleMail); 
            system.debug('emails'+emails);
        }
    }  
    system.debug('emails'+emails);
    Messaging.sendEmail(emails);
    return null;
}
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Rishi Golyan , But getting error on  Variable does not exist: a.Name                                                                              efa.setFileName(a.Name);
efa.setBody(a.Body);
 fileAttachments.add(efa);

Comment: Edited please check.